# Detect if a BLE scan response is sent when a scan request is received in Android App

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have developed an android app for my mobile in which I am advertising 13-bytes of data in advertisement packet. I have setup another BLE device which is in observer mode which catches this advertisement packets and sends a scan Request. I want to detect this scan request in my android app and send a scan response. Once I send the scan response I want to stop advertising and turn off Bluetooth in mobile. My mobile is sending the scan response but how to detect it so that I can stop advertising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that information is not exposed over the HCI layer. The Bluetooth controller simply sends a scan response without notifying the host about that.

Comment: Isn't there anyway atleast to detect a request being catched by the advertiser?

Comment: There is no such thing defined in the HCI standard. Some vendors may have introduced vendor-specific events for that but that's nothing you will normally get through the Android Bluetooth API. You should instead initiate a connection to the advertiser and send over a message that it has received the data.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. I researched a lot on internet but nowhere received this info.

Comment: @Emil It looks like the HCI spec defines a "LE Scan Request Received Event" with Event Code 0x3E. See Vol 2, Part E of the Core Specification at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification

Comment: Yes! That's a new feature of Bluetooth 5.